Is it posible to catch the a "timestamp" from a canvas element created with Adobe Animate?
The idea is to syncronize simple js animations that have dynamic data with Adobe Animate canvas that have more animation capabilities. Trying to find if that is possible. I know it is possible with the video component. But not sure about canvas.
